# How implements CORS with Javascript, jQuery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, cors, java-8

I am having trouble consuming a rest service that did. Already implemented a CORS filter in my Java application, but when I use the `$.ajax()` it returns the problem of CORS. Using `$.getJSON` can access the method, however I can not add headers on it.

I need to know how to add the header in `$.getJSON` or how to make it recognize the CORS I added in my Java service.

I'm using Java 8, Wildfly 8.1-Final, RestEasy, etc.

My ajax like this:

```js
var url = "http://pacoteiro-trysoft.rhcloud.com/api/v1/pacote/RC824435750CN";

$.ajax({
    async : true,
    type:'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    cache:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        "token":"123"
    },

    success: function(data) { 
        alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!", data);
    },



 error: function(data) {
        alert("Erro!", data);
    }
});
```

and my filter this way:

```
@Provider
public class ConfigureCORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "application/json, origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

Comment: "but when I use the $.ajax() it returns the problem of CORS" what problem with CORS, any error message?

Comment: in which domain you working on? localhost or directory system or the server?

Comment: I don't get it - I never had to do anything special on the client side, its the -browser- that adds the extra CORS headers to the request. I second the question asked: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Braiam 
when i use it shows me a message to put the script on the same server that the rest service. but when i use $.getJSON it detects a CORS filter present in my code Java, but i dont know put headers into a $.getJSON.

Comment: @V31 I working in a server on Openshift. Wildfly 8.1-Final

Comment: is the first part of the answer of mine crossDomain true working for you @PedroHenriquedeOliveiraSil?

Comment: Error: Request from blocked sources: the same origin policy prohibits reading in remote http://pacoteiro-trysoft.rhcloud.com/api/v1/pacote/RC824435750CN?_=1408707184194 resources. This can be corrected by moving the resource to the same domain or activating the CORS.

Comment: But i active the CORS!

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request you can make use of crossDomain option in order to enable CORS

```
$.ajax({
    async : true,
    type:'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    cache:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain:true,
    headers: {
        "token":"123"
    },

    success: function(data) { 
        alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!", data);
    },



 error: function(data) {
        alert("Erro!", data);
    }
});
```

If you working on a directory system then you need to disable the chrome security and allow CORS validation on your local system. To do this go to your chrome.exe folder (I am talking about windows over here) and execute this command:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: So the problem was that I add the missing Java CORS filter an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with the word **token**, I'm going through in my `headers` in AJAX, I'll put the answer below.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to add word **token**:

```
  responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "token, origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
```

`CORS` in my `filter` in Java, since I'm using it in the `headers` AJAX. The complete solution is this:

```
@Provider
public class ConfigureCORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "token, origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
          responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```